# PHP PDO MySQL - Printing many-to-many relationships in a HTML/Bootstrap Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, many-to-many

I am doing a project here where i had to learn everything fast so i could be able to do my class, however i am pretty newbie in PHP and i need a LOT of help here :(

I need to print the many-to-many relation ship in my tablet, however i don't know what to do for my case: i tried tons of ideas, however i may have done something wrong because none worked >.<

Here is the table printed (*the last one "Surfactante" i put the "Marca" result, however "Surfactante" is in a N x N relationship with Product with a table of their on "produto_surfactante" with (codProd,codSurf)*):
[image]

Here is the function i am using to print:

```
public function dataviewProd($query)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
    {
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            //takes the name of "Marca"
            $codM = $row['codMarca'];
            $stmtM = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT nomeMarca FROM marca WHERE codMarca = :codM;"); 
            $stmtM->execute(array(":codM"=>$codM));
            $nomeMarca = $stmtM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['nomeMarca'];

            ////takes the name of "Tipo de produto"
            $codTP = $row['codTipoProd'];
            $stmtTP = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT nomeTipoProd FROM tipodeproduto WHERE codTipoProd = :codTP;"); 
            $stmtTP->execute(array(":codTP"=>$codTP));
            $nomeTipoProd = $stmtTP->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['nomeTipoProd'];

            //this one should take the names of all "surfactantes" separated by ","
            $nomeProd = $row['nomeProd'];
            //$stmtPSV = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT s.nomeSurf
                                            //FROM produtosurfview psv
                                            //  INNER JOIN surfactante s
                                            //      ON psv.Surfactante = s.codSurf
                                            //WHERE psv.NomeProduto = {$nomeProd};");
            //$stmtPSV->execute(array(":nomeProd"=>$nomeProd));
            //$stmtPSV->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            //$prodsurf = $stmtPSV->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


            ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php print($row['codProd']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['nomeProd']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['tipoCab']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($nomeMarca); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($nomeTipoProd); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($nomeMarca); ?></td>
            <td align="center">
            <a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' href="alterarProduto.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['codProd']); ?>" role='button'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></a>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
            <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href="deletarProduto.php?delete_id=<?php print($row['codProd']); ?>" role='button'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td>Nada ainda cadastrado...</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }

}
```

I kept one idea i tried here, however, as i said, i had to learn fast and adapt, so it's very possible that i am doing a newbie mistake here, that's why i need help ^^'